# cmis query not giving result on redhat server

Tags: java, alfresco, alfresco-share, cmis, opencmis

**My Query is :**

```
SELECT * FROM cmis:document WHERE CONTAINS('PATH:\"/app:company_home/st:sites/*\"')
```

> This Query is working fine in **Windows and Ubantu also ** but it is not working on Red Hat server.

Is I am missing any property or anything else.
Please help for the same.

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion server is causing this?

Comment: because same Query is working fine on my local machine (Window) and same query is not working on Red Hat server.

Comment: Yeah, but my point is that you don't have the same database, same documents, same indexes on your local machine and on your server (maybe you do?), and the problem most likely lies in one of those.

Comment: yes you are right but I am able push documents on my RedHat server but not fetch documents from it.

SELECT cmis:path,cmis:objectId,cmis:allowedChildObjectTypeIds FROM cmis:folder where CONTAINS('PATH:\"/app:company_home/st:sites/cm:havells/cm:documentLibrary/')

This query is not giving me any objectId 
but same is working in other environment

Comment: I had setup the alfresco environment the same way as on Ubuntu, mysql is used as database in both cases, but the Ubuntu seems to work fine and RHEL is not able to return results. The query is not giving any exception or error.

Comment: I have found the solution. Mistake from side.

Comment: Why don't you post your solution as an answer, and soon enough you'll be able to mark is as accepted one?